# Consequences of the Recursion Theorem

Tags: computation-theory

I had an exam today on computational theorey and a question came up "state two consequences of the recusion theorem".
Out of curiosity what would be the correct answer to this. I wrote that it enabled the production of recurisve computer viruses and im wondering what would be other consequences and if im using consequences in the right context. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably the question was aksing for mathematical consequences. The wikipedia article states some direct consequences for decidability questions: [Recursion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem). I cannot see any direct connection to viruses.